# Identifying a Facebook user id from a url?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I've been playing around with the Facebook graphs api for a while, and to the best of my knowledge you shouldn't be able to get a Facebook user's id from their username.

I then came accross [stalkscan.com](http://stalkscan.com) and note that they do just that. You provide a Facebook url and the resulting queries contain that usernames profile id.

How can I acheive a similar result with or without the graphs api?

Comment: There is no API. The only way to do it is scraping which is not allowed

Comment: @WizKid Do you believe the example site is accomplishing it with scraping? Seems unlikely given the speed (but possible).

Comment: There is no other way so yes that is what they do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a facebook user id by using the following endpoint:

```
URL /?id={url}
```

{url} represents an external URL as it relates to the Facebook social graph - shares and comments from the URL on Facebook, and any Open Graph objects associated with the URL. (e.g. a user, a page...).

With Python, you can use something like this:

```
import requests

USER_URL = '' # your link
ACCESS_TOKEN = '' # your credentials
params= {'id': USER_URL,'access_token': ACCESS_TOKEN}
fb_graph = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/"

r = requests.get(fb_graph, params=params)
fb_id = r.json().get('id')

print('Facebook User ID: %s' % fb_id)
```

Full documentation of the graph API is available [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/url).

Comment: Although this looks on the right path in testing the JSON just re-retreives the url. I'm aiming to retrieve the integer id for the user (for future requests). It does work for pages, but not users. Any ideas?

Comment: @Codingo the idea is that you don’t do it, because Facebook does not want you to. You get a user id to use for API requests, when people log into your app. Your app should not be dealing with users that have not logged in to it and granted it permission to access their data in the first place.